# Using set-url for a remote repository did not change when entering command git remote -v

Tags: git

I've been trying to switch my git settings from ssh to https and found that I could do that through `set-url`; however, when I tried to switch my remote url from ssh to https, it did not work. Here is the situation:

`>git remote set-url origin [url format]`

```
>git remote -v
origin [ssh format] (fetch)
origin [ssh format] (pull)
```

Does this have something to do with other ssh settings in git?

I tried `set-url`, changing my username, but the remote repository remained in ssh form and did no change to https.

Comment: What is the output of `git config --list --show-origin | grep -Fi insteadof` ?

Comment: There is no output.

Answer (score 0):

Try and confirm the change actually took place by editing directly your `repo/.git/config` file.

If the config file itself has not changed after your `git remote set-url origin` command, then, as commented, look for an `insteadOf` setting which would force Git to use SSH insteadOf HTTPS.